# Accept an OK answer or write more complete answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, etiquette

I have a [question over at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/500525/how-can-sleeping-processes-in-top-be-using-a-percentage-of-cpu) and it was been answered to my satisfaction. And I have two options as I see it

1. Mark the given answer by David Schwartz as "the answer"
2. Write up a summary answer with more details

I am inclined to go with option 2) but I don't want to deprive David of points. What is the best etiquette in this instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We really like detailed answers. Future visitors might have great use of it.

But of course there should be the need for more detail. If you feel you can add real value to an existing answer then edit that one. Or if it would change the original answer too much then write your own.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that; as a courtesy I just asked the person if it was OK that I edited their answer.